# GeoMesa on HBase faster import

Tags: hbase, geomesa

I am using GeoMesa v1.4.0 on HBase v1.2.6.
Currently I am importing and indexing my data with the help of the *HBaseQuickStart* class. Unfortunately, the runtime for large files is very long. 
Does someone know of a bulkLoad with GeoMesa to speed up my process?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, GeoMesa provides ingest through the binary distribution command line tools. You have to define a 'converter' file that has the mappings from your input files to your simple feature type. Once you have that, you can run locally with multiple threads, or remotely using map/reduce. The documentation for the Accumulo command is [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/accumulo/commandline_tools.html#ingest), the HBase command will work the same but have slightly different parameters. The documentation on installing the HBase tools is [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/user/hbase/install.html#installing-the-binary-distribution).

If you want to keep your Java ingestion code, then you'll need to do something custom. There is an example of writing a map-reduce ingestion [here](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-examples-gdelt.html).